# libgl - failed to load driver: vboxvideo

Tags: virtualbox, opengl, mesa

I'm attempting to run [this code](https://gist.github.com/je-so/903479) to create a transparent xlib window with openGL features, but when I run the program I get these errors in the terminal:

```
libGL error: pci id for fd 4: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerOutputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameteriNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinalCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glDeleteFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinishFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGenFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFenceivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glIsFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glSetFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
```

And the window just looks like this after it's been moved: (the background doesn't update since it's launched)

[image]

(I'm using a custom desktop enviroment I made)

I searched around and found these errors had to do with running Ubunutu in Virtualbox on windows hosts, but they where thought to have been resolved a couple years ago.

My system is:
Ubuntu LTS 14.04.3 running on a Windows 8.1 host with the latest version of virtualbox and guest additions, 3D acceleration enabled, libgl and mesa-utils installed (until I installed mesa-utils the background was just solid white, so it's progress!)

**EDIT 1:**

As posted here https://askubuntu.com/a/324814/462342 by user [Max](https://askubuntu.com/users/178577/max), turning off 3D acceleration does indeed fix most of the issues. Now the only errors I'm getting are:

```
libGL error: pci id for fd 4: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
```

And the window works as expected.

Does anyone know a fix that doesn't require turning off 3D acceleration?